# How to have a space between algorithm lines

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, algorithmic

I have an algorithm and I would like to insert space between its steps.

Here is my try:

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Output:}}
\newcommand{\sfunction}[1]{\textsf{\textsc{#1}}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicforall{\textbf{foreach}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicindent{.8em}
\begin{document}
       \begin{algorithm}
     \caption{my algorithm}
            \label{alg:ALG1}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \State $\text{For each line} of my algorithm I would like to insert a space between the steps but I cannot do that. The text goes out the box.$
    \State $i \gets \textit{patlen}$
    \If {$i > \textit{stringlen}$} \Return false
    \EndIf
    \State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
    \If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}
    \State $j \gets j-1$.
    \State $i \gets i-1$.
    \State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
    \State \textbf{close};
    \EndIf
    \State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
    \State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide preamble part, i.e., from \documentclass to \begin{document}

Comment: @MadyYuvi Ok. I will in a minute.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I have added them.

Comment: @Maryam Could you make them easily compilable?

Comment: @Maryam Your code provides some error, can you provided error free file?

Comment: @Maryam: Instead of using `\State $\text{your text}$` for a `\State`ment of code, just use `\State your text`, without the `$\text{...}$`.

Comment: @Werner your comment worked and solved the problem. I search for the same problem but found nothing. I hope that you may post an answer so this will be helpful for other users.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I have corrected the error.

Comment: Glad to hear that Werner's suggestion works for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have line wrapping "enabled" you need to set your text as regular text, not in math mode wrapped inside `\text`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State For each line of my algorithm I would like to insert a space 
      between the steps but I cannot do that. The text stays inside the box.
    \State Something else altogether.
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```